# How to center "text-align: left" when wrapping text?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way in which my title text is always centered but letting it wrap on the left instead of the center, here's my markup so far:

```css
.title-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#900, #990);
}

.title-container__text {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <h1 class="title-container__text">Gran Teatro Sara</h1>
</div>
```

This maintains the text centered up until the point where the screen size is too small and the text has to wrap, once it wraps the whole text aligns to the left and leaves a big space on the right... I would like to maintain the text wrapping like this, but to have equal space both on the left and the right.

I hope I made myself clear.

I'll explain myself with some visuals, the current behavior of the centering and wrapping goes like so:
[image: Big screen sizes works jus fine]

[image: wraps as desired, but content does not center]

The above example works just fine when viewing from big screen sizes

When the screen gets smaller the text wraps as I want, but the text **stop being centered**. My desired outcome goes like so:

[image: Example desired behavior]
[image: Example desired behavior even smaller screen size]

Comment: It sounds like you want to have the text box inside another (invisible) box which has a Left/Right margin so your textbox internally is left aligned but that box itself is centred. Flexbox can probably do this but I can't tell you how off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to add gutters on either side with `flex: 1` and a max-width of your choosing – pixels or percentage, as in this snippet:

```css
.title-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#900, #990);
}

.title-container__text {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ddf;
}


.gutter {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 10%
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="gutter"></div>
  <div class="title-container__text">Gran Teatro Sara</div>
  <div class="gutter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will have to take a look at this solution, the code you shared adds too much gutter on the right for big screen sizes. In any case thanks a lot, now I have an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Add "text-align: center;" to your .title-container CSS.

```css
.title-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#900, #990);
}

.title-container__text {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <h1 class="title-container__text">Gran Teatro Sara</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to maintain text wrapping and have the wrapped text be centered?